# If $cf(\kappa)=\lambda$, then is every sequence of length $\lambda$ cofinal in $\kappa$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Take $\omega_1$ for instance.  Let's say I have a sequence of (distinct) ordinals of length $\omega_1$.  Will this sequence be cofinal in $\omega_1$?

Comment: If you aren't certain whether a thing is obvious, then it isn't.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question about $\omega_1$ is yes, but the answer to the title is in general no.

For $\omega_1$, note that, for each $\alpha<\omega_1$, your sequence of distinct ordinals contains only countably many terms $\leq\alpha$, so, from some point on, your sequence is above $\alpha$.  Since $\alpha$ was arbitrary (below $\omega_1$), this means your sequence is cofinal in $\omega_1$.

But for the general situation, consider $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$ (also known as $\omega_\omega$), so $\lambda=\omega$.  The identity function on $\omega$ is obviously not cofinal in $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: Hi, Andereas Blass. Your answer is nice +1).

Comment: But in general my question is true if $\kappa$ is regular ($\kappa=\lambda$)? Thanks

Comment: @DavidL.  Yes, it's true for regular cardinals $\kappa$.  The proof is the same as for $\omega_1$; just replace "countably many" with "fewer than $\kappa$".